# Como funciona la facturacion de lectura de firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

tengo una duda acerca de que es lo que cuenta par que aumenten las metricas de lectura en el firestore, osea

las operaciones de lectura se refiere a las peticiones get post put... ? osea las que se muestran en la ventana de network del navegador?

o es la cantidad de documentos individuales de la firestore, ejemplo si en una peticion me trae 200 documentos, me cuentan 200 mas operaciones de lectura, o solo 1

Comment: Está claramente explicado en la [página de precios](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing?hl=es): *Cuando utilizas Firestore, se te cobra por lo siguiente: - **El número de documentos que has leído, escrito y eliminado.** - **La cantidad de almacenamiento que utiliza tu base de datos**, incluida la carga de metadatos e índices. - **La cantidad de ancho de banda de red que usas.*** Si en una operación lees 200 documentos, te computan 200 documentos, si borras 400, te computan 400, si actualizas 300, te computan 300. En Firestore debes hilar fino con las lecturas en bucle y cosas así.